# Elasticsearch java api filteredQuery

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have this query used with Exists API from elasticsearch (1.4.4) :

```
curl -XPOST 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_search/exists' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "message": "2014-12-04 00:00:01 CET Tx[XXXXXXXX] cmd[INSERT] PID[XXXX] DB[XXXXX] LOG: some log info here ;-) \r"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term" : {
                    "some_field" :"some_value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

This works fine (return **true** when it has to be) but when I tried to do the same with java API like this :

```
    Client client = this.createClient();

    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(
                    QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("message", "the same message"),
                    FilterBuilders.termFilter("some_field", "some value")
                );

    System.out.println(queryBuilder.toString());
    ExistsResponse response = client.prepareExists("existsMessage")
        .setTypes(type)
        .setIndicesOptions(IndicesOptions.fromOptions(true, true, true, false))
        .setQuery(queryBuilder).execute().actionGet();

    System.out.println(response.exists());
    client.close();
```

But the result is **always false**! So I print the request build by the and it's different than want I wanted. So is there a way to do exactly my first request from source json or other way using api builders?

**Edit :**
The output of queryBuilder.toString()) :

```
{
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : {
      "match" : {
        "message" : {
          "query" : "the same message\r",
          "type" : "phrase"
        }
      }
    },
    "filter" : {
      "term" : {
        "some field" : "some value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the builder print?

Comment: @ChrisGerken The output when print it. I read in doc that _match_ with _"type" : "phrase"_ is the same than _"match_phrase"_. But the construction is far away different and it is missing the query DSL at first level.

Comment: you are not using types and you are not setting indices options in the REST example. Can you make sure the query is the same?